# Recursive copy through directory to same folder CMD

Tags: for-loop, cmd, copy

This is probably pretty basic, but I'm hitting a brick wall. I have several subfolders within a directory that have multiple Microsoft Access Runtime Application (.accdr) files in each subfolder. I need to make a copy of each .accdr, change the extension to .accdb, and drop each into the same existing subfolder.

The command I have working if I cd to each subfolder is:
`copy *.accdr *.accdb`

I was hoping I could recursively go through the whole directory and execute this command so I wouldn't have to cd to each folder. However what I've written is not working. From the output, it seems to cycle through each folder, but it doesn't make any .accdb copies. The error just says "The system cannot find the file specified."

```
FOR /R "c:\directory\" %F IN (.) DO (
copy *.accdr *.accdb
)
```

What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you can do it with this routine:

```
Sub dirTest()

    Dim dlist As New Collection
    Dim startDir As String
    Dim i As Integer

    startDir = "C:\foxpro2\"
    Call FillDir(startDir, "*.dbf", dlist)


    MsgBox "there are " & dlist.Count & " in the dir"

   'lets printout the stuff into debug window for a test

    For i = 1 To dlist.Count
        Debug.Print dlist(i)
    Next i

End Sub

Sub FillDir(startDir As String, strFil As String, dlist As Collection)


    Dim strTemp As String
    Dim colFolders As New Collection
    Dim vFolderName As Variant

    strTemp = Dir(startDir & strFil)

    Do While strTemp <> ""
        dlist.Add startDir & strTemp
  strTemp = Dir()
    Loop

    strTemp = Dir(startDir & "*.*", vbDirectory)

    Do While strTemp <> ""
        If (GetAttr(startDir & strTemp) And vbDirectory) = vbDirectory Then
            If (strTemp <> ".") And (strTemp <> "..") Then
                colFolders.Add strTemp
     End If
        End If
        strTemp = Dir()
    Loop

    For Each vFolderName In colFolders
        Call FillDir(startDir & vFolderName & "\", strFil, dlist)
    Next vFolderName

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! I'm not very familiar with VB. Is there no way to do it with CMD or batch?

Comment: Well, you probably can do this via batch file - but I'm good with VBA, and poor with batch files (sorry). In VBA, you can rename a file with "name". I see you removed the ms-access tag (and that is 100% fair on your part). Hopefully some batch file person can chime in.

Comment: That was done for me by dbmitch, but I suppose it makes sense, since the filetypes don't necessarily play a part in the code. Thanks again for the input! I'll try to dip my toes into VBA.